# Java Script Logging

Tags: logging, javascript

My Intention is to write all the javascript log messages into a file. For that I have used log4js library.But, it is having its own limitation . That is , Log message can be written in to a file only in IE(For Other browser(like Firefox) ,netscape.security.PrevilageManager is undefined and so on Chrome).

Can any body suggest me , which library shall I follow to accomplish my requirement. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try with [NodeJS file system](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html) or [Javascript File Object](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/js-file-object.html). Hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: Is this library same as log4js or what ? @Hoa Hoang